# PHP Rename Using Array Values

Tags: php

I've searched this exchange AND Google for the problem I'm facing. No results. So I once again turn to you.

Here's the case: I have a great amount of file names in an array, including their respective paths. This array is dynamically generated.

I need to rename the files in this array.

I though I'd put the rename in a foreach to loop over each file.

```
foreach($files as $value) {

rename($value,"downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/gmp-guideline-pics-".$LFocus."-".$Title);

}
```

I get the following error from PHP:

```
Warning: rename() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /home/users/whatever/whatever/test.php on line 58
```

And indeed when I do a var_dump on $value, I get the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(95) "downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_038_1_aide_memoire_on_assessment_of_qrm_implementation (1).pdf" }
```

The things is though, I can't figure out how to get $value from an array containing a string, to just the string.

I hope you guys can help me out!

A var_export($files):

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_038_1_aide_memoire_on_assessment_of_qrm_implementation (1).pdf', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_021_2_aide_memoire_on_gmp_gcp (1).pdf', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_024_2_aide_memoires_on_biotech (2).pdf', ), 3 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_023_2_inspection_of_quality_control_laboratories (2).pdf', ), 4 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_009_3_aide_memoire_on_utilities (1).pdf', ), 5 => array ( ), 6 => array ( ), 7 => array ( ), 8 => array ( ), 9 => array ( ), 10 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pe_008_4_site_master_file_copy1.pdf', ), 11 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_011_3_recommendation_on_computerised_systems (5).pdf', ), 12 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_005_3_parametric_release.pdf', ), 13 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pe_010_4_guide_to_good_practices_for_the_preparation_of_medicinal_products_in_healthcare_establishments_copy1.pdf', ), 14 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_014_3_recommendation_on_isolators.pdf', ), 15 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/ps_w_01_2015_joint_pics_ema_concept_paper_on_the_revision_of_annex_1.pdf', ), 16 => array ( ), 17 => array ( ), 18 => array ( ), 19 => array ( ), 20 => array ( ), 21 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pe_005_3_pics_gmp_guide_for_blood_establishments.pdf', ), 22 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pe_011_1_pics_gdp_guide_copy1 (1).pdf', ), 23 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_008_3_guide_to_plasma_inspections.pdf', ), 24 => array ( ), 25 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/ps_inf_20_2011_qa_distribution_activities_for_apis_may_2010.pdf', ), 26 => array ( ), 27 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_012_3_recommendation_on_sterility_testing.pdf', ), 28 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_020_3_smf_plasma_warehouses_copy1.doc', 1 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_020_3_smf_plasma_warehouses_copy1.pdf', ), 29 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_019_3_smf_source_plasma_establishments.doc', 1 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_019_3_smf_source_plasma_establishments.pdf', ), 30 => array ( ), 31 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_006_3_recommendation_on_validation_master_plan.pdf', ), 32 => array ( ), )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, so `$value` is an array. Access it accordingly:

```
foreach($files as $value) {
    rename($value[0],"downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/gmp-guideline-pics-".$LFocus."-".$Title);
}
```

Using the `var_export()` you provided, it looks like you also loop through the values (Which can also be an array). Notice this:

```
[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_020_3_smf_plasma_warehouses_copy1.doc
        [1] => downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_020_3_smf_plasma_warehouses_copy1.pdf
    )
```

Array index 28 has 2 files in it, so we need 2 foreach loops. If the array is empty, the inner foreach loop will simply do nothing. (See [this playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/l2nT4fXxiQ5fF8Wu)):

```
<?php
$files = array ( 
    0 => array (
        0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_038_1_aide_memoire_on_asse‌​ssment_of_qrm_implem‌​entation (1).pdf', 
    ),
    1 => array ( ),
    2 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_021_2_aide_memoire_on_gmp_‌​gcp (1).pdf', )
);

foreach( $files as $values ) {
    //You may have multiple values, so we need to loop through them.
    foreach ( $values as $value ) {
      rename($value, "downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/gmp-guideline-pics-".$LFocus."-".$Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suck at arrays so I'm glad you are willing to help, PHP provides me with this: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/users/whatever/whatever/test.php on line 58 Line 58 being: rename($value[0],"downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/gmp-guideline-pics-".$LFocus."-".$Title)

Comment: @JulianKoster This is the same exact code where you `var_dump()`'d `$value`?

Comment: Do `var_export($files)` right above the foreach loop, and post it here.

Comment: It's messy! array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_038_1_aide_memoire_on_assessment_of_qrm_implementation (1).pdf', ), 1 => array ( ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'downloads/gmp-guidelines/pics/pi_021_2_aide_memoire_on_gmp_gcp (1).pdf', ), 3 => and so forth (the comment became too long)

Comment: @JulianKoster Edit your original question with the full `var_export()`. This array is a mess (The elements don't even line up the same).

Comment: Done! I've added the var_export.

Comment: See my updated edit. (Updated again @JulianKoster) You need 2 foreach loops.

Comment: Whoops, thought you had a bunch of questions that weren't accepted (They were answers)